# Esri Dijit Claro.css theme is not read by application

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, esri

I am writing an application in asp.net using c#, javascript and css. I am using esri javascript api and esri dijit themes.

The claro.css theme is not being read by the application. It is the only css with this problem. When I check in the web debugger inspector, the theme is not listed for the div anywhere in the inspect list. The two other esri dijits (popup.css and esri.css) are being read. My custom theme viewer.css is being read. I did have to put in an override for my viewer.css theme or else the esri.css kept reading over it. Without using override claro my custom css page will not be overridden by the esri.css . If I remove the override claro, the claro.css is still not read and the custom css is overridden by esri.css .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"     "https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Cool Map</title>

    <%--Inside GIS Style Sources--%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/App_Themes/viewer.css"  />

    <%--Outside Style Sources--%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.4/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" runat="server"/>
    <% if (false) {%>
        <link href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.4/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <% } %>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.4/js/esri/dijit/css/Popup.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.4/js/esri/css/esri.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.4/"></script> 

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../arcgis_js_v34_api/arcgis_js_api/library/3_4/3_4/init.js"></script>    -->  

<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/Common.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/format.20110630-1100.min.js">
    <%--//Used to format numbers to look like currency https://code.google.com/p/javascript-number-formatter/--%>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/Config.js">

</script>
    <script>

function Load(){
    map code
}

</script>
</head>
<body class="override claro">
 <div id="rightPane"  dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="right">
         <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer">
             <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="legendPane" title="Legend"  >
                 <div id="legendDiv"></div>
             </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (false)`, what is that suppose to mean?

Comment: @Hackerman : if (false) is a suggestion I read elsewhere to try and force the reading of the css. It worked for the other person but not for me.

Comment: Just get rid of `<% if (false) {%>` and the `<% } %>`

Comment: @mplungjan : I am posting server code because from all that I have read, that is where the problem is most likely coming from and modification to the server code is most likely the path to fixing the problem. I am not aware of modifications I can make to the client to fix the problem. If you have a client code suggestion I will be more than happy to try it.

Comment: Get rid of those lines, clean your project, rebuild and clear your browser cache.

Comment: If you had posted only client code, it would have been clear that the claro.css simply weren't there. Then we could blame something on the server. Now this time it was easy to spot the `if (something never true) { include something that will never be included }` code

Comment: @Hackerman : I have taken out the <% if (false) {%> and the <% } %> but it is still not working. The claro.css still does not even appear in the styles list for the debugger Elements inspector.